# Generating an array of random numbers summing to a constant

Tags: python, random

I'm using a Dirichlet distribution to generate an array of random numbers which sum to 1. However, I actually think I need these numbers to sum to an arbitrary constant.

```
import numpy as np
d = np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(10), size=1)
```

I'm confused about a good way to modify this so that the sum is, say 10. Presumably:

```
10*d
```

isn't a good way to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `N*d` is a legitimate way to modify your random numbers to sum to `N=10`. The [Dirichlet random numbers are samples from a Gamma generator that are normalized to sum to 1](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.dirichlet.html) (see also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Gamma_distribution)). Since you want them to sum to `N` instead of 1, it's completely legitimate to just multiply each Dirichlet random number by `N`.